# python list manipulation nesting vertically, making it look like a matrix

Tags: python

I have the following list. In python it looks like `[15,20,25,35,-20... etc]`

```
15  20  25  35  -20 -15 -10 -5
10  15  20  25  -25 -20 -15 -10
5   10  15  20  -35 -25 -20 -15
```

I want to nest vertically like so:

`[[15,10,5],[20,15,10],[25,20,15],[35,25,20],[-20,-25,-35],...etc]`

So it involves some kind of a transpose operation, but counting backwards, e.g. transpose would give you `[5,10,15]` and not `[15,10,5]` for the first item in the list

What's the best way to do it? (shortest and most readable code)

If anybody also have suggestions on shortest run time would be also helpful for bigger datasets.

Comment: Depending on what else you're doing, this might be a good opportunity to explore NumPy: http://www.numpy.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the elements with the list comprehension and then transpose it with `zip` function, like this

```
data = [15, 20, 25, 35, -20, -15, -10, -5, 10, 15, 20,
        25, -25, -20, -15, -10, 5, 10, 15, 20, -35, -25, -20, -15]
length = len(data) / 3
data = [data[i:i + length] for i in xrange(0, len(data), length)]
```

Till this point we grouped the data like this

```
[[15, 20, 25, 35, -20, -15, -10, -5],
 [10, 15, 20, 25, -25, -20, -15, -10],
 [5, 10, 15, 20, -35, -25, -20, -15]]
```

Now, we just have to transpose `data`, with `zip`

```
print zip(*data)
```

**Output**

```
[(15, 10, 5),
 (20, 15, 10),
 (25, 20, 15),
 (35, 25, 20),
 (-20, -25, -35),
 (-15, -20, -25),
 (-10, -15, -20),
 (-5, -10, -15)]
```

`zip(*data)` means we unpack all the elements of `data` and pass each of the elements as parameters to `zip`. It is equivalent to

```
zip(data[0], data[1], data[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
lst = [15, 20, 25, 35, -20, -15, -10, -5, 10, 15, 20, 25, -25,\
       -20, -15, -10, 5, 10, 15, 20, -35, -25, -20, -15]

# Python 3
l = len(lst) // 3
# Or a single slash in Python 2: l = len(lst) / 3

# Just for diversity
a = [itemgetter(*range(x, x+l))(lst) for x in range(0, len(lst), l)]

pprint(list(zip(*a)))
```

Output:

```
[(15, 10, 5),
 (20, 15, 10),
 (25, 20, 15),
 (35, 25, 20),
 (-20, -25, -35),
 (-15, -20, -25),
 (-10, -15, -20),
 (-5, -10, -15)]
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. `a` does not look like what you have, it's just a running list without nesting. I group it like that to visualize it better.